# Windows 8 laptop does not show WiFi

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I have a Windows 8.1 machine that previously connected to a wireless modem but it does not now.  The modem is not a problem because I can see it and connect to it from other computers.

On the Windows machine when I click on the Network icon in the notification area under Connections  I only get Broadband.  A  few days ago I got the WiFi connection listed there and I could connect to it.  Now I get nothing listed.

In the control panel under Network and sharing center when I try to Connect to the internet, only Broadband is listed.

I  see Set up a new connection.  When I click on Set up a new network I  wait 90 seconds and nothing happens.

The Connect to a workplace did not help.

I tried restarting everything.

Thanks!

Comment: I would check to make sure the device is enabled. Right click the network icon in your taskbar tray -> Click "Open Network and Sharing Center" -> Then click "Change Adapter Settings" on the left. When you advance to the adapter list, right click your WIFI adapter and make sure it is enabled.  Also, is this a laptop? Make sure you haven't bumped the WIFI card switch on the side of it.

Comment: If Windows Update has recently run, you can try reverting to the pre-update state. Another option would be to try and reinstall the driver.

Comment: Uninstall the driver to the wireless adapter.  You will then need to install the current device driver for the adapter yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound was correct.  Replacing the driver worked.  Thanks!!!  If you want to write an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I am not able to write answer here, but the problem is that your router has channel set as 'auto'. So all you need to do is to set up channel Manually to a number (between 1-8) and your pc will recognize your wifi. (8.1 has a problem with channels > 8)

Comment: Set Channel from auto to 1-8 solved my problem!! Thanks Darpan!